# Add columns to table based on other rows and columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements, row, multiple-columns

For example, I have the following table in SQL Server:

| name | from | to | traveling date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | london | Paris | 5/jan/2022 |
| Mike | Paris | Barcelona | 5/jan/2022 |
| Sam | Cairo | Riyadh | 6/Mar/2022 |
| Sam | Riyadh | Dubai | 6/Mar/2022 |
| Sam | Dubai | Maldives | 7/Mar/2022 |
| Sam | Maldives | Riyadh | 13/Mar/2022 |
| Sam | Riyadh | Cairo | 13/Mar/2022 |

And the result I want must have new columns based on other columns and rows, like below:

| name | from | to | traveling date | Route | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | London | Paris | 5/Jan/2022 | London-Barcelona | 5/Jan/2022 |
| Mike | Paris | Barcelona | 5/Jan/2022 |  |  |
| Sam | Cairo | Riyadh | 6/Mar/2022 | Cairo-Maldives | 6/Mar/2022 |
| Sam | Riyadh | Dubai | 6/Mar/2022 |  |  |
| Sam | Dubai | Maldives | 7/Mar/2022 |  |  |
| Sam | Maldives | Riyadh | 13/Mar/2022 | Maldives-Cairo | 13/Mar/2022 |
| Sam | Riyadh | Cairo | 13/Mar/2022 |  |  |

As you can see Sam had Round ticket he reached the next day of traveling and stayed for couple of days in Maldives.

All I care about is to consider Route as 1 ticket and have the traveling date from 'Date'.

Help please.

Comment: How do we know Sam didn't go from Cairo to Dubai as one trip and then from Dubai to Riyadh to Cairo as another trip? Why isn't Sam's trip Cairo to Cairo?

Comment: Generally, airlines consider a single trip direction to have all stopovers less than 24hrs. But you don't include time info